# How do I request a variable from the webserver using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, variables, webserver

I have a loop in my JavaScript that is constantly checking the variable `EventCounter`, if eventcounter is zero then it proceeds to do an action then increment it ++, And then it proceeds to do nothing, until that variable changes, here is the code:

```
EventCounter = {{eg.globals.EventCounter}};      

for(var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                r = rects[i];
                ctx.strokeRect((r.x*sc)|0,(r.y*sc)|0,(r.width*sc)|0,(r.height*sc)|0);
                window.rects = rects[i];                    
                //console.log(EventCounter);
                if (EventCounter === 0) {               
                    console.log("event counter is" + EventCounter)
                    //setTimeout( function () {document.getElementById("sb").click()}, 5000) 
                    EventCounter++
                    console.log("event counter is now " + EventCounter);                            
                }

            }
        }
```

Now the EventCounter global variable gets its value from the webserver (its a python webserver and its a python variable).

But my question is how do I detect that the variable has changed on the webserver? an ajax request right? how would I go about requesting the variable value to detect if it has changed so that loop can run again? (**the server is incompatible with PHP)

Comment: An AJAX request would certainly do this, but I hope you're not proposing to poll a server continuously for this information. You should look at setInterval to reduce the polling frequency as well

Comment: Well for the sake of wondering how its done with AJAX, lets say websockets isn't an option. How would I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets), which allow a server to send a message to a browser whenever it wants to, once a connection is established. You handle the incoming message with a Javascript event handler, thus avoiding the need to poll continuously.

WebSockets are suported by all major browsers, including IE10. You'd have to make sure, of course, that your server application can support WebSockets too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use WebSockets like Mike W suggests.

Also you could write a script on your python server that returns JSON when it's called and then have the variables you want and their values in the JSON file. This will be supported for all browsers instead of just modern ones like WebSockets require.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery implementation that polls the server script every 1000ms and displays the result. Your typical response time + browser processing time should be significantly less than your polling interval or your requests might back-up.

**Javascript:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>eventCounter</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                                    // this is where your ajax call is made.
                $.ajax('geteventcounter.php', {
                  cache: false,
                  dataType:'json',
                  success: function(data) {
                                            // do your browser-side processing here.
                    $('#eventCounter').text(data.eventcounter);
                  }

                });
            }, 1000);            
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<p>eventCounter is <span id=eventCounter></span></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Server side PHP:**
For this example, uses a session variable which it increments on every request and returns a JSON string.

```
<?php
session_start();
    // initialise counter, or increment it.
if (isset($_SESSION['eventcounter'])) {
    $_SESSION['eventcounter']++;
} else {
    $_SESSION['eventcounter'] = 0;
}
    // set output mime type
header("ContentType: application/json");

    // copy session variable to a new array, convert to JSON and send.
echo json_encode(['eventcounter' => $_SESSION['eventcounter']]);

?>
```

Comment: server is not compatible with php

Comment: You asked how to request a variable with AJAX. I've given you an example, and for completeness I provided the PHP script I used to test it.  This is not supposed to be a final solution - you will need to adapt it to your needs, and bring it up to production standard yourself.