# How do I make a news feed which continuously updates with information from a database using continuous server-side processing?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am trying to set up a news feed that continuously updates with new articles based on a complex algorithm that predicts which articles the user will be most interested in. Because the articles are continuously coming in to the database, and the interest algorithm would be very browser-intensive, it would need to be run server-side. How would I make a page continuously update with information doing much of the processing server-side? **Preferably with PHP, Javascript and MySQL**

Answer (score 2):

If you really have to have a continuous feed then take a look at [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets). However, you probably only need a polled solution for this, refreshing every few seconds. There's a sample implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101285/how-do-i-request-a-variable-from-the-webserver-using-ajax?noredirect=1#comment24763399_17101285)

Comment: The complicated part is having the server run the processing every few seconds without refreshing

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand your comment. With web sockets the server pushes its updates whenever it chooses and the browser handles the refresh. If you're using a polled solution the browser requests updates and handles the refresh. In either case the server processes as it will and doesn't perform any refreshes.

Comment: Sorry, I am unfamiliar with WebSockets, and misunderstood how it works. I will look further into it.